# Reusing pages in WinJS's Pivot

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, winjs

I'm developing app for Windows Phone 8.1 using WinJS and I used Visual Studio's template for pivot application. My Applications queries external API and displays results in `PivotItem`. Since there are three very similar queries that reurn same type of data, I'd like to reuse one code for all the sections in `Pivot`. The `PivotItem` page consist basically only of `ListView` with items received from API. My section page javascript looks like this:

```
var ControlConstructor = WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/pages/bookmarks/sectionPage.html", {
    ready: function(element, options) {
    //Here I call API based on received option and render the page
    }
}

WinJS.Namespace.define("bookmarksApps_SectionControls", {
    SectionControl: ControlConstructor
});
```

My page declaring the Pivot looks like this:

```
<div class="bookmarks" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.Pivot" data-win-res="{ winControl: {'title': 'BookmarksTitle'} }">

    <div class="section1 section" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.PivotItem" data-win-options="{ isHeaderStatic: true }" data-win-res="{ winControl: {'header': 'BookmarksNew'} }">
        <div class="sectioncontrol" id="section1contenthost" data-win-control="bookmarksApps_SectionControls.SectionControl" data-win-options="{'section': 'new'}"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="section2 section" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.PivotItem" data-win-options="{ isHeaderStatic: true }" data-win-res="{ winControl: {'header': 'BookmarksAll'} }">
        <div class="sectioncontrol" id="section2contenthost" data-win-control="bookmarksApps_SectionControls.SectionControl" data-win-options="{'section': 'all'}"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="section3 section" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.PivotItem" data-win-options="{ isHeaderStatic: true }" data-win-res="{ winControl: {'header': 'BookmarksHistory'} }">
        <div class="sectioncontrol" id="section3contenthost" data-win-control="bookmarksApps_SectionControls.SectionControl" data-win-options="{'section': 'history'}"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Now, when I open the app,pivot page correctly loads and displays first section with data. But when I swipe the different section, new data is loaded (so the ready function is called, but nothing is displayed (page is blank, only PivotItems' headers are visible). But if I swipe back to section1, it contains data, that I want to display in section2.

Is it possible to reuse my `SectionPage.html` and `SectionPage.js` in different PivotItems, preferably without too much of boilerplate code?

Comment: have you tried using Templates ? check this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700705.aspx

Comment: I'm using `itemTemplate` already, but my problem is somewhere else. I want to share HTML and JavaScript for the whole page, item template is only small part of the HTML part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found source of my problem. In page `/pages/bookmarks/sectionPage.html` I had `<div>` with an id meant for holding my ListVIew. And I was getting win control for listview using `document.getElementById("listViewId").winControl`. This is wrong, because then I had three divs with same id (each for every section), so `getElementById` was always returning same list (the one on the first section).

So I changed getting of the wincontrol to

```
var discussionList = document.querySelector("#" + contentHost + " .disucssionsListView").winControl;
```

where `contentHost` depends on `data-win-options` received from main page and everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create custom HTML control which will host these pages, custom control can accept uri as data-win-options, then inside your control you can have updateLayout() which will render the page and append to parentElement.

---

Sample code in update layout method:

```
            var options = {} //Page options
            if (!this._isLoaded) {
                this._isLoaded = true;
                WinJS.UI.Pages.render(this.uri, this._pageElement, options);
            }
```